# Wordpress php adding login form to menu not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code in a custom plugin file.

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_login_logout_link', 10, 2); 
function add_login_logout_link($items, $args) {                 
    $logoutlink = wp_logout_url( home_url() );

    $user = get_current_user_id();    
    $dashboardlink = get_dashboard_url($user);
    $blogs = get_blogs_of_user( $user );

    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        $items .= '<li class="menu-button grey menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children"><a class="top-level" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Actions</a>';
        $items .= '<ul class="sub-menu">';

        if($blogs) {
            foreach ( $blogs as $blog ) {
                $items .= '<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children"><a href="">' .  $blog->blogname . '</a>';
                $items .= '<ul class="sub-menu">';
                $items .= '<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="http://' . $blog->domain . $blog->path .'"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i> Visit <span style="font-style:italic;">' .  $blog->blogname . '</span></a></li>';
                $items .= '<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="http://' . $blog->domain . $blog->path .'wp-admin"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Go to dashboard</a></li>'; 
                $items .= '</ul>';
                $items .= '</li>';
            }
         }

         $items .= '<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="'.$logoutlink.'"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Logout</a></li>';
         $items .= '</ul>';
         $items .= '</li>';  
    }

    $items .= '<li class="menu-button grey menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children"><a class="top-level" href="#">Login</a>';
    $items .= '<ul class="sub-menu login-form">';
    $items .= '<li><div class="login_form_dropdown">'.wp_login_form(array(
        'echo' => false,
        'redirect' => site_url( '/your-account/ ' )
    )).'</div></li>';
    $items .= '</ul>';
    $items .= '</li>';

return $items; 
}
```

The idea here is that if a user is logged in, a menu item called "Actions" which has a dropdown of a users sites (it's a multisite install) and links to their dashboard for each site is shown.

The last part of the script is intended to show a login menu link and login form as a dropdown, when the user is logged out.

However, currently, both links show only when the user is logged in, nothing shows when the user is logged out.

Can anyone see why this might be happening?
Thanks

Comment: Is this a multisite installation?

Comment: @ohgodwhy yes (see in question)